# Flask-SocketIO running app but not firing events

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

So I'm building a simple Flask social media application that uses Flask's session ids. I want to remove a user's session id whenever they leave the page so that they have to re-login. I did a little research and found out that Flask-SocketIO allows you to do that through the 'connect' and 'disconnect' events. However, when I run the app, and I open up the site/log on to the page, nothing happens. I don't get any output from the connect event nor the disconnect event when I close the tab. Here's the full code.

```
# Starting/Initialisation of App
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///app.db'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY
socket_io = SocketIO(app=app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Socket IO Events
@socket_io.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    print("Connected!")

@socket_io.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    # TODO Fix this socket io disconnect event. It's not working for some reason. Just figure things out with socketio
    print("Client Disconnected")
    print("YOOOOOOOOOO")
    session.pop('id')

@socket_io.on('message')
def on_message():
    print("Exit message")

# App Routes
# A page where a user can login to an account
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    # If user submits form
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Get response and user's Account object from db
        # if query does not return None aka user is in database
        # Check if response's password is the same as the user's password
        # If it is, redirect to homepage
        # Else if not, return an "invalid password" error

        form = request.form # User Response
        user = Account.query.filter_by(email=str(request.form['email'])).first() # Query for user

        if user is not None: # Validating query
            if str(form['password']) == user.password: # Checking password
                session['id'] = user.id
                return redirect('/home')
            else:
                return "Invalid password"
        else:
            return "Invalid email or password"
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

# Run App
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket_io.run(app)
```

I'm don't receive any errors or whatsoever so I'm really confused.

Below is my `pip freeze`

```
bidict==0.21.2
click==8.0.1
colorama==0.4.4
Flask==2.0.1
Flask-SocketIO==5.1.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
greenlet==1.1.0
h11==0.12.0
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
python-engineio==4.2.0
python-socketio==5.3.0
simple-websocket==0.2.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.22
Werkzeug==2.0.1
wsproto==1.0.0
```

Would really appreciate it if anyone has any solutions to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to consider here:

1. print statements to stdout won't necessarily show in your output with Flask, I believe stderr does, so you might want to try either that or the logger, e.g.:

```
print('Connected!', file=sys.stderr)
app.logger.info("Connected!")
```

2. Are you sure you have the right version of the client?  I don't believe the client is included with Flask-SocketIO, and Flask-SocketIO isn't compatible with the latest client version (4).  You should be using client version 3.1.3 (https://socket.io/docs/v3/). This is the version of the SocketIO library you include (this example truncated from the aforementioned SocketIO docs and updated to show an alert box once connected so you can be sure it's worked):

```
<html>
<body>
...
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-cPwlPLvBTa3sKAg    ddT6krw0cJat7egBga3DJepJyrLl4Q9/5WLra3rrnMcyTyOnh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
const socket = io("ws://localhost:5000");

socket.on("connect", () => {
  // either with send()
  alert("You're connected!");
  socket.send("Hello!");

  // or with emit() and custom event names
  socket.emit("salutations", "Hello!", { "mr": "john" }, Uint8Array.from([1, 2, 3, 4]));
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

3. does your web console in your browser show any errors?  Are you sure the client side code is correct and you're connected?
   Viewing the Javascript console varies from browser to browser, but will show you any errors encountered in your Javascript.  In Chrome for example, you click the 3 dots to the far right of your address bar, then More Tools -> Developer Tools.  This is cruicial in debugging Javascript issues.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but I don't follow. I'm not sure what 'client' you're referring to. I'm new to this. Sorry! :( Could you elaborate further? But yea, I just tried the first and last options. Didn't do much. Still isn't working. But how would i tell if I'm connected, can you explain the last part of your third point and elaborate on the 2nd point?

Comment: Oh, when you say 'client', are you talking about my browser? If so, how would I downgrade my client version?

Comment: I've expanded on the previous points.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Huh, yeah it did work after I changed `https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js` to `https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.js` because with the first link there was an error showing up about a ReferenceError to `io`. Does that mean the only way I can detect connections and disconnections is through JavaScript? I can't use Flask-SocketIO? Because right now Flask-SocketIO doesn't work but JS's socket.io works.

Comment: If socketio is connecting successfully, and you see that alert box, then your server should be functioning correctly also.  If you don't see any output to your console for the connect/disconnect events I would double check my point 1.  Even without your messages you should see some output relating to connections as you are running in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have included socket.io in client side means in html. you can include this script in your head in html to include it.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
```

Then you need to define socket in your javascript file or script tag.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    socket = io.connect(document.href );
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        // do something when user connects
  });
  socket.emit("message",data) // data is sent to flask
</script>
```

for more information, refer to the documentation.

https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/